# How to edit a single text line in BASH?

Tags: bash

BASH v3.2

I use the command:

```
read -e name
```

which allows basic editing of what I'm typing. What I'm looking for is a command or script that prints an initial single string in a variable, which is then editable and with adjustable maximum length. Maximum string length would be 40 characters or so. Like a tiny, tiny text editor. AFAIK that cannot be done with the read command.
Some functions would be delete, insert, backspace, left/right arrow keys, ESC (restore old text) and ENTER.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not use something like `vi` or `nano` ? or is that not a file at all?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, it has to work inside a bash script. That is why I need a read-like command or a script. I am not happy with dialog (or whiptail). Read works ok but misses some functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As Mohammad mentioned, you can invoke a regular editor to do this, though applying some restriction like length are tricky.

Alternatively, install `dialog`.

```
var=test
var=$(dialog --stdout --title "Example" --backtitle "my title" --max-input 10 --inputbox "Please change the variable" 8 50 "$var")
echo $var
```